# SQL get last month name

Tags: sql, datetime

Following command giving me current month (March) in short form.

```
SELECT  left(datename(month, getdate()), 3)
```

But i need last month Feb.

I meant whenever i run this command will give me last month name.

What would be the sql command?

Comment: sounds like you should be able to do month - 1 ...??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT left(datename(month, dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())), 3)
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you are using T-SQL:

```
SELECT left(datename(month, dateadd(month,-1,getdate())), 3)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT left(datename(month, dateadd(m,-1,getdate())), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT left(datename(month, date_sub( getdate(), interval 1 month ) ), 3)
```

This will work for MySQL (you didn't specify your SQL server), might need something similar to `date_sub` for different DBs.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT left(datename(month, DATEADD(MM,-1,getdate())), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select left(datename(month, dateadd(month, -1, getdate()),3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT` `DATENAME(MM,DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE()))` AS 'The Name of last Month'

- to print Name of the particular day we have to use `DATENAME()` function. So, we used this function here for that purpose.
- `MM` represents month here.
- `-1` is used in Date function to get previous month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TSQL, you're going to want to incorporate the DATEADD() function into that query:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

wrap getdate in that and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select substring(DATENAME(MONTH,getdate()),1,3)
```

i think it will help you much better

Regards,
Azarudhin S.